# QuerySets are lazy in template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-queryset

I am working on one question and answer website.I think i have mess with code.I am sending querysets all objects when only one needed.

Like sending all answer of one question when only one needed.
I print only one.

So at that time  will it affect database's all record or only record which i will  print in template?

**View.py**

```
questions = Question.objects.all()
context = {
    'questions':questions
}
return render(request,'index.html',context=context)
```

**template_tag.py**

```
@register.simple_tag
def getmostvotedanswer(answers):
    answer = answers.order_by('-vote')[0]
    return answer.answer
```

**index.html**

```
  <p>{% getmostvotedanswer question.answer_set.all %}</p>
```

In this i am sending all answers but only needed so ***will it affect database's performance?***

**Question Model**

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    uid = models.ForeignKey("User",on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,default=1,related_name='user_q_id_set')
    vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    catitle = models.ForeignKey("Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    editUser = models.ManyToManyField("User",related_name='user_q_edit_set',null=True,blank=True)
```

**Answer Model**

```
class Answer(models.Model):

    answer = models.TextField()
    qid = models.ManyToManyField("Question")
    uid = models.ForeignKey("User",on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user_a_id_set')
    vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    editUser = models.ManyToManyField("User",related_name='user_a_edit_set',null=True,blank=True)
```

Comment: What does your `Question` model look like?

Comment: @Reez0 Here it is

Comment: So you just want to display the question with the most votes?

Comment: No i wanted to display question with most voted answer @Reez0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your templates, you are iterating through questions, passing **all** the answers to your custom template tag and find the one with the most vote.

If that's what you want, you can simply put ordering into your answers model like this:

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    # ...

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-vote']
```

This way, when you call `question.answer_set`, it will automatically sort the answers by the `vote` field.

So you can say `question.answer_set.first` to get the top voted answer.

Comment: Oh ty This solve so much and improve perfomance too.This is so simple.